# Handling / Performing / Managing tasks in Userform with the help of keyboard ( shortcut keys )

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform, word-2007

I have a `User-form` [image: userform]

For most of `Check-Boxes`/ `Buttons` I assigned a `Key`. Can be execute by pressing:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Assigned-key</kbd>

I had googled the following code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.PASTE.Accelerator = "V"
Me.CEEMEA.Accelerator = "C"

End Sub
```

Problem is I have to Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to perform any given task.

Q. Is there any short way of doing this without pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>Key?

**My progress After Robin's Original-Answer**

Firstly I set focus on <kbd>Macros</kbd> Button.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.Macros.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Then on `Macro_Keydown` `Event` I put the following code.

```
Private Sub Macros_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    If KeyCode = vbKeyB Then
    Bulgaria.Value = Not Bulgaria.Value
    ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyE Then
    Estonia.Value = Not Estonia.Value
    ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyH Then
    Hungary.Value = Not Hungary.Value
    ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyA Then
    Latvia.Value = Not Latvia.Value
    ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyL Then
    Lithuania.Value = Not Lithuania.Value
    ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyM Then
    Macedonia.Value = Not Macedonia.Value
    ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyP Then
    Poland.Value = Not Poland.Value
    ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyR Then
    Romania.Value = Not Romania.Value
    ElseIf KeyCode = vbKeyU Then
    Ukraine.Value = Not Ukraine.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi - regards your new method using `SetFocus` on the `Macros` button - I can see that working as long as the user doesn't change the focus to another control. If you want to be able to toggle the `CheckBox` value between on and off then in your `Macros_KeyDown` handler, use this for example: `Bulgaria.Value = Not Bulgaria.Value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Updated answer

The original answer didn't really meet the brief because whilst handling the `UserForm` events for e.g. `KeyDown` works for a form with no other controls, it doesn't work for a form with controls. This is because the event only works when the form has the focus. When the form has other controls, it never receives the focus. Also, it is not possible to set the focus onto the `UserForm`. Almost all forms will have some other controls, so the original answer is practically useless. So let's shamelessly adapt an idea from [Andy Pope on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9815d901-8f5c-40f4-8603-61e7bdbc71ea/event-handler-for-all-objects-on-a-userform?forum=isvvba) to meet the OP's requirements.

First, insert a VBA `Class` into the project with this code:

```
Public WithEvents m_objGroupCheckBox As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub m_objGroupCheckBox_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    MsgBox "Keypress was: " & Chr(KeyCode) & " on " & m_objGroupCheckBox.Caption
    Select Case Chr(KeyCode)
        Case 1:
            UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value = Not UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value
        Case 2:
            UserForm1.CheckBox2.Value = Not UserForm1.CheckBox2.Value
        Case "3"
            UserForm1.CheckBox3.Value = Not UserForm1.CheckBox3.Value
    End Select
End Sub
```

The `Class` defines a generic event handler for a `CheckBox` on the `UserForm`. For the purposes of this example, we will make key presses of 1, 2 and 3 toggle the checkbox state for the 3 `CheckBox`s on the form.

Second, put the code in the `Userform`'s initialize event. It creates a collection of this custom class that references back to the original checkboxes created on the `UserForm`.

```
Private m_colCheckBoxes As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim lngIndex As Long
    Dim objGroupCheckBox As clsGroupCheckBox

    Set m_colCheckBoxes = New Collection
    For lngIndex = 1 To 3
        Set objGroupCheckBox = New clsGroupCheckBox
        Set objGroupCheckBox.m_objGroupCheckBox = Me.Controls("CheckBox" & lngIndex)
        m_colCheckBoxes.Add objGroupCheckBox, CStr(m_colCheckBoxes.Count + 1)
    Next

End Sub
```

So now, if we have a `UserForm` in the designer like this, with each CheckBox named `CheckBox1`, `CheckBox2` and `CheckBox3`:

[image]

Then, our generic event handler will allow us to define a single place to handle the `KeyDown` event and set `CheckBox` status in one spot.

[image]

## Original answer - not as useful as it looks :(

You can directly handle the `KeyDown` event of the `UserForm` and enter your specific logic in there. Maybe you should check out `KeyUp` and `KeyPress` as well depending on how you think the form will work.

MSDN notes that *'..."A" and "a" are returned as the same key. They have the identical keycode value. But note that "1" on the typewriter keys and "1" on the numeric keypad are returned as different keys, even though they generate the same character.'* - [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834507.aspx)

You can handle SHIFT, CTRL and ALT as well.

```
Private Sub UserForm_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode >= vbKeyA And KeyCode <= vbKeyZ Then
        MsgBox "You pressed " & Chr(KeyCode)
    ElseIf KeyCode >= vbKeyF1 And KeyCode <= vbKeyF12 Then
        MsgBox "Function time!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I put this in my userform it work only once. I Don't understand the problem. I searched it says there is something called `focus` preventing msgbox? can you help

Comment: I have controls on `userform`  that's why its not working.
What should I do . kindly help me out.

Comment: @IbneAshiq Look at the list of events for the individual controls (right-hand box in the VBA code window when the control is selected in the left-hand window). You'll find the equivalents of what Robin describes that are appropriate for the individual control types.

Comment: @CindyMeister I manage to add above code in one `check-box`s `KeyDown event`  just to test, and found out that it only work when particular `check-box` is focused. So I think for my question above, All of the check-boxes needed to be focus at initial stage so that when `User-form` appear I can press a button to check mark.  hope U understand :)?

Comment: @CindyMeister in simple words.When I press `B` button on keyboard then `Bulgaria` will be checked and When I press keyboard `C` then `CEEMEA` button will be pressed, so on. Can U help plzz?

Comment: @IbneAshiq - I updated the answer with something you can try out in your application. Using the `KeyDown` event of the `UserForm` won't work with the other controls, as you have discovered. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Robin I Mange to use your `original Answer` and have some progress in it . may be you should look and see if I am doing it right ? for new answer I will try it sooner when I finish with Original answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
'VBA Shortcut Keys not work in UserForm [Partially Solved]

Public Sub CallSub() 'code must be in Module
'-do this code-


Private Sub Workbook_Activate() 'code must be in (ThisWorkbook)
Application.OnKey "^{f5}", "callSub"

'^ this code only work with Excel Worksheet not in Userform


Private Sub XxX_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer) 'code must be in Userform with SHOWMODAL = False
If KeyCode = 17 Then AppActivate "microsoft excel"  

'XxX means all CommandButton and Textbox and Listbox and Combobox
'Keycode 17 is Ctrl Key if you are using Ctrl+F5 - when you press Ctrl it will activate Excel Worksheet
```